# Error : can't read "line2": no such variable in tcl

Tags: tcl, puts

I have a script with this snippet:

```
 while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
 if {[string first "Modem :" $line] != -1} {
            set line2 [string range $line 17 end]
            puts $fout "One : \t$line2"
    }

    puts $fout "Two : \t$line2"
 }
```

The `One :` works and prints the output (when i don't include the `Two :` part in the script) but when I include `Two :` , it shows

```
error : can't read "line2": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $fout "Two : \t$line2""
    ("while" body line 14)
```

Doesn't it hold the value of `line2` after coming out of `if` ?

Comment: If the first line in `$fin` didn't have the substring `Modem :`, then you won't get into the `if` and `line2` doesn't exist yet... What are you trying to do?

Comment: But i'm sure, there is the substring. I've seen the file

Comment: Is it in the **first** line of the file? If not, then you get the error.

Comment: iam trying to build a table.. by `grep`ing for two substrings in two such `if` statements. And then outside the `if`s i use `puts $fout "$line1\t$line2"`

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get your above 2nd comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>From chat, [this](http://pastebin.com/Xvx4yPfw) is a sample of `$fin`.</sub>

The problem with the code is that `while {[gets $fin line] != -1}` loops through each line of `$fin` one at a time, and not a whole bunch together. `read` is the command that gets all lines in one variable.

This means that when the first line is read, you don't have `$line1` or `$line2` in the first iteration of the loop and thus, `puts` will fail to retrieve a variable by those names.

My proposed solution is to get each of the required variables first and when everything is gathered for the 'blocks', print them all at once.

```
set fin [open imp_info r]
set fout [open imfp_table w]

puts $fout "LINK\tModem Status"
puts $fout "----\t------------"

while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {

        # If there is "wire-pair (X)" in the line, get that number
        regexp -- {wire-pair \(([0-9]+)\)} $line - wire_pair_no

        # Last column, get the value and puts everything
        if {[regexp -- {Modem status: ([^,]+)} $line - status]} {
               puts $fout "$wire_pair_no\t$status"
        }

}
```

Output:

```
LINK    Modem Status    
----    ------------
0       UP_DATA_MODE
1       UP_DATA_MODE
```

Answer (score 0):

If with the first line you read in this loop:

```
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    if {[string first "Modem :" $line] != -1} {
        set line2 [string range $line 17 end]
        puts $fout "One : \t$line2"
    }
    puts $fout "Two : \t$line2"
}
```

you do not have a “`Modem :`” somewhere on it, the condition is not satisfied and the variable is not touched when processing the `if`. The following `puts` fails because the `line2` variable hasn't been set to anything yet; there's just no variable there, and the `$` syntax doesn't like that at all.

One possible fix is to set `line2` to something before the start of the loop:

```
set line2 "DUMMY VALUE"
```

Or maybe you should change what variable you're reading there to `line` instead of `line2`.

```
puts $fout "Two : \t$line"
```

Or maybe you should test whether the variable exists before reading it:

```
if {[info exists line2]} {
    puts $fout "Two : \t$line2"
}
```

All will work, but they do different things and I don't know what you want…

Comment: It's possible to do “clever” things with traces to make obvious variable semantics fail to work. Don't Do That. Really. (It's unlikely you'd do this without knowing about it.)